# How to create File open dialogue box in javascript that will show files on server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

I have a webpage in which the clients should be able to open files on server, I need to open a file open dialog box, similar to:

`<input type= "file"  id = "select_file" onchange = "openfunction();"</input>`

but this shows files available on local machine, it should list files available on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use already existing solutions like [elfinder](http://elfinder.org/), because it's already solved problem and you certainly don't want to implement all this UI/UX yourself again.

There is no tag in HTML which will allow you to select file from server. You will have to implement everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<input type="file">` you cannot read server files since it is a post action to post the whole file and there is no such option at all to read file from server!!

The possible solution would be either to create a `HTML UI` for all the files existing in the server like `dropdown` or `checkbox` and then ask user to select the files required and perform necessary option.